# Alternate entry on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I'm doing a promotion for one of my apps with Deutsch Telekom, and they want me to put my app on a discount for their carrier exclusively. They have told me to achieve this by uploading a second version of my app to the Google Play Store, with the reduced price, and make it available only in that region on that carrier.

Is there a way I can duplicate my project in Eclipse without having to recopy all the files every time I update the original, but give the copy a different package name so it can be uploaded separately to the Play Store? Making my project a Library seems reasonable, except you can't export a Library Project, so that would hinder my development of the original app.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm doing a promotion for one of my apps with Deutsch Telekom, and they want me to put my app on a discount for their carrier exclusively. They have told me to achieve this by uploading a second version of my app to the Google Play Store, with the reduced price, and make it available only in that region on that carrier.

Congratulations!

(assuming they're not forcing you at gunpoint to do this)

> Making my project a Library seems reasonable, except you can't export a Library Project, so that would hinder my development of the original app.

Here's what I would try:

Step #1: Make your existing app project a library project.

Step #2: Make a standard app project, referencing the library project. Copy the manifest from the library project to this project. This should then build your original app as it was.

Step #3: Make another app standard project, referencing the library project, cloning the other standard project's manifest, but then updating its package to whatever you want the DT edition to be.

Comment: Okay! So, I did this, and the app referencing the library project and having the original package name is working as expected. The app referencing the library with the new package name is giving me errors about all my XML files, things like "String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent')."

Comment: @Nick: That sounds like a build target issue. Make sure your build target of your new-package project is the same as the build target of your old-package project. Also, if they *are* forcing you at gunpoint to do this, cough twice in your reply. :-)

Comment: Ah, yes, that did the trick :) And no, they're not forcing me at gunpoint haha, I'm very excited to have them contact me like this. Thanks again!