# Widgets referenced from library view errors

Tags: android, reference, android-appwidget

so I just created a new app that is references an older app of mine, using it as a library. You can see that problem/solution here:

[Alternate entry on Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934876/alternate-entry-on-play-store)

However I've just noticed that my new app is giving me error views when I try and set down some of the widgets, with LogCat output such as:

```
03-29 20:48:17.899: E/AppWidgetHostView(456): Package name com.nickavv.cleanwidgets not found
03-29 20:48:17.899: E/RemoteViews(456): Package name com.nickavv.cleanwidgets not found
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.android.launcher2.AllApps3D
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:930)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:219)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:155)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.createView(AppWidgetHost.java:218)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.completeAddAppWidget(Launcher.java:911)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.onActivityResult(Launcher.java:542)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Class not allowed to be inflated com.android.launcher2.AllApps3D
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.failNotAllowed(LayoutInflater.java:525)
03-29 20:48:17.960: W/AppWidgetHostView(456):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:472)
```

What's going on here? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was in the fact that I was using RemoteViews for the widgets, and in setting up some of the remote views, I was hard-coding the package name from the original application. The solution was to replace the hard-coded package name with context.getPackageName()

Comment: strange, I already had getPackageName, and it prints the correct package name in the log, and still sometimes after I upgrade the app (or just run it on the device from AndroidStudio) the widget disappears. Later it got back after another upgrade

Comment: @Gavriel This is still happening for me. Have you found the solution?